# Printer is not printing colour on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing

I have Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP 650 laptop.

I have a printer Samsung C48W attached via wifi.

I can make printouts from Linux Ubuntu, but only MONOCHROME, i.e. no colours.

The printer itself is ok. I works fine from Windows.

I downloaded the latest driver package V1.00.39_01.17 from HP, and installed it.

That did not help.

If I understood correctly the driver is a PostScript driver.

The printer is set to "Auto" under "Emulation type". I also tried the explicit "PostScript" setting, but no change.

Still no colours on the printout, just monochrome.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Using any browser, access the CUPS admin page at `http://localhost:631/admin/`.

LeftClick on `Manage Printers`.

LeftClick on your printer name.

Note: sometime, during this process you will be prompted for a Username/Password - use your login credentials.

In the `Administration` drop-down list (LeftClick and Hold), select the `Set Default Options' item.

Ensure that the `Output Mode` is set to `Color`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still not working. Color Mode is set to colour. This issue is the same also on my friends laptop. The funny thing is that when I print to another printer of slightly different model Samsung C460W the colour printing works fine. So I'm beginning to suspekt a bug (?) in the driver. Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't even have ```Output Mode``` in the 'Set Default Options' item :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem made more confusing as a Test Print page would come out perfectly but all my images would come out in monochrome. I tried suggestions from this board and other sources but none solved the problem. So I used CUPS to delete the printer (Epson L220). Once done I used CUPS to find the printers on my system and then proceeded to install it (with the L220 using the driver for the L210) Problem solved!

Comment: Back to the drawing board - solution worked for one document only. Doing the Delete and Install above again didn't produce the same results No color - just grayscale output.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: no color on my HP4520, settings always falling back to monochrome.

I fount a simple solution here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/printing-in-color-not-working-any-more-solved/113907/3

In short: install system-config-printer an run it. In the printer-icon right-click and select 'properties' --> 'Job Options' and scroll down to 'Other Options (Advanced)'. Then, in the 'print-color-mode' select 'color'. OK and exit. Works on my Kubuntu 23.04 alfa.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to applications and click the "Settings" app
2. Click on "Printers" in the left column
3. Click on "Additional Printer Settings" button in the bottom right
4. Double click on printer icon for your printer
5. Click on "Job Options"
6. Scroll to the bottom
7. Under "Other Options (Advanced)" change "print-color-mode" to "color"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was it for me. It seems, that when I set the color option to monochrome in "Printer Options" this setting also switches to monochrome. But it never switches back to color.

Comment: In my case the only option available under print-color-mode is monochrome.

Comment: The problem came back with one of the updates since then.  And this fix no longer works. :(  I am going to have to buy a new printer.  It won't be buying a Dell printer again! LOL

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 20.04. test page would print in colour but applications wouldn't. The only solution I found is in each app the check the "Black & White" setting in the Advanced tab when I click print:

[image: Advanced Settings Tab]

Somehow this seems to get reset all the time to "On"