# Enabling Two-Sided Printing in Ubuntu-23.04

Tags: networking, printing, duplex-printing

Running Ubuntu 23.04. I had problems with hplip-gui crashing and couldn't do a network installation of a HP ColorLaserJet printer.  A post on this forum suggested edits to
a configuration file.  I made these edits, and now the  hplip-gui app works, I have the printer installed, and it correctly prints color files.  But, and for me, this is a very big but, there does not seem to be any way to enable two-sided printing.  Am I missing something simple.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printer is not printing colour on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130360/printer-is-not-printing-colour-on-ubuntu-18-04)